# Flutter inspector not showing selected widget's code in VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

While inspecting widgets if on inspection of select widget mode. Widget inspector not showing that widgets code in VS code. I have used GetX package for state management.

[image]

Activated DevTools in Web

Should be able to inspect code from Widget inspector mode in VS Code.